# How to get an encryption key from file

Tags: python, google-chrome, dictionary, encryption

I'm trying to get the encryption key from Google Chrome and I get an error saying:

```
line 13, in find_crypt
print(encrypt['encryption_key'])
KeyError: 'encryption_key'
```

The code is:

```
from genericpath import exists
import win32crypt
import json
import os

def find_crypt(path):
    path = path.replace('\Default', '')
    
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file == 'Local State':
            f = open('{0}\\{1}'.format(path, file), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
            encrypt = json.load(f)
            print(encrypt['encryption_key'])

def find_passwords(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file == 'Login Data':
                pass

def main():
    local = os.getenv('LocalAppData')
    roaming = os.getenv('AppData')

    directories = {
        'chrome' : local + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default'
    }

    for name, directory in directories.items():
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            continue
        else:
            find_crypt(directory)
            find_passwords(directory)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please [edit], and indicate the line with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The ***Local State File*** does not store any **key** with the name **encryption_key** but instead with **encrypted_key**.

That is why your Python Program **yells** [at the line 13] it cant find any key with the name **encryption_key**.

Also the **encrypted_key** is inside another object with the name **os_crypt**

Enough Talking, Here is the modified code :)

```
def find_crypt(path):
    path = path.replace('\Default', '')
    print(path)
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file == 'Local State':
            f = open('{0}\\{1}'.format(path, file), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
            encrypt = json.load(f)
            print(encrypt['os_crypt']['encrypted_key'])
```